# Handsontable edit on mobile device

Tags: handsontable

i know that handsontable is not mobile friendly but is there a workaround that we can edit on mobile devices with the newest version?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I use Handsontable version 0.25.1, but I imagine the situation is still the same at the very latest release.

My experience is only with iPad device (iOS 9); I cannot speak about all mobile devices.

I found the rendering acceptable.  But if you tap a cell to edit nothing happens, which is rather limiting!  I made just two small changes to rectify:

Tracing all of this right down in `handsontable.full.js`, the logic in `onCellMouseDown()` is testing for `event.button === 0` (i.e. left mouse button) to start setting up for recognising the double click to activate the mobile text editor.  On a touch device, they are explicitly calling their `onMouseDown/Move/Up()` from their `onTouchStart/Move/End()`, passing the mouse events the `event` structure received for the touch event.  However, touch events' `event` structure does not have a `button` member, so that is `undefined`, causing bad behaviour.

Directly setting passed-in `event.button = 0` before passing to mouse event handlers solves this.  Put in line:

```
event.button = 0; // set as left mouse button
```

into `onTouchStart()` [prior to call to `onMouseDown(event)`, around line 1326] & `onTouchEnd()` [prior to call to `onMouseUp(event)`, around line 1368].

Now tapping into a cell correctly allows editing.  It brings up their `MobileTextEditor`.  Which I did not like for a number of reasons, including the fact that often it appears behind the on-screen keyboard so the user does not even know it is there!  I changed their `Handsontable.TextCell` [around line 4346] so that the `editor:` line now reads:

```
  editor: (isMobileBrowser() && Handsontable.useMobileEditor) ? getEditorConstructor('mobile') : getEditorConstructor('text'), // only use mobile editor if explicitly called for
```

So it uses the standard in-place text editor, which I prefer, unless you go `hot.updateSettings({useMobileEditor: true})`.